# Excluding tables with database first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Is there a way to exclude tables when running the `Scaffold-DbContext` command?

I tried something like

```
Scaffold-DbContext -provider EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer 
       -connection "xxx" -OutputDirectory Models 
       -Tables "dbo.a,dbo.b,dbo.c,dbo.d"
```

but I get `Build failed`

Comment: Can you just removed it afterwards?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch no because tables I don't want are causing problems because they do not have primary keys

Comment: The tables parameter accepts single dimensional string array, you just need to change it to array format {"dbo.a", "dbo.b", "dbo.c"}.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch now the error is `No coercion operator is defined between types 'System.String' and 'System.Char'.`

Comment: @Dr.Stitch but this works "dbo.a","dbo.b","dbo.c","dbo.d", ie. without {} thanks for the help!

Comment: can i post an answer and kindly marked it? for points. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Tables parameter accepts single dimensional string array, you just need to change it to array format:

```
"dbo.a", "dbo.b", "dbo.c"
```

Thanks Bread!